# How to show red flag icon in Salesforce LWC using SLDS?

Tags: html, salesforce, lwc

I am writing a lightning html code to display red flag using the SLDS. However, I only see grey flag. Can you help me to get the red variant of the icon? Thank you!

```
 <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:priority" alternative-text="priority!" variant="priority" title="warning variant small" size="small"></lightning-icon>
```

[![Grey Flag][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikNC8.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **variant="error"** which will display the icon in the red color

```
  <lightning-icon 
              icon-name="utility:priority" 
              alternative-text="priority!" 
              variant="error"
              title="warning variant small" 
              size="small">
      </lightning-icon>
```

Comment: Great thank you!!!!! However, I figured it out.